# Is there a way to parametrize 'Workspace' in Team Build 2010 for different branches?

Tags: dynamic, tfsbuild, workspace

Good morning'

Team Foundation Server 2010 question.

Do I need to create a Build Definition for every branch I have ?

Is there a way to parametrize 'Workspace' in Team Build 2010 for different branches, so we could just queue a new build specifying the workspace paths?

I tried finding out how TFS retrieves the workspace paths from the workspace used in the build, but the xaml got me clueless since there are parameters for everything except the mapped paths.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to create a Build Definition for every branch I have ?

No, but you may want to in order to have a cleaner implementation.

> Is there a way to parametrize 'Workspace' in Team Build 2010 for
>   different branches, so we could just queue a new build specifying the
>   workspace paths?

Yes- but it isn't as straight forward (unless you are using .proj files still).

If you are using the upgrade template and still using proj files:

[Building multiple branches, can I use paramters to identify the target branch.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/tfsbuild/thread/368dc51c-ad81-4e6c-a4ef-9df8eb91bc48)

If you are not using the upgrade template, this answer posted on SO will help point you in the right direction:

[How to make build definition in TFS Build 2010 configurable w.r.t input variable values and “items to build”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572736/how-to-make-build-definition-in-tfs-build-2010-configurable-w-r-t-input-variable)